# Usb storage doesn't mount

Tags: mount, usb, scsi

I'm connecting my LinkitOne to my arch linux pc, and it doesn't mount.
When I'm connecting same Linkit One to windows pc and another arch linux pc it works as it should.

Here is `dmesg` output on my pc with problem:

```
[авг24 10:44] usb 3-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 57 using xhci_hcd               
[  +0,094393] option 3-1.2:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected                     
[  +0,000058] usb 3-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0             
[  +0,000219] cdc_acm: probe of 3-1.2:1.1 failed with error -16                           
[  +2,754820] usb 3-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 57                                 
[  +0,002076] option1 ttyUSB0: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0 
[  +0,000007] option 3-1.2:1.0: device disconnected                                       
[  +0,918541] usb 3-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 58 using xhci_hcd               
[  +0,097752] usb-storage 3-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected                     
[  +0,000141] scsi host6: usb-storage 3-1.2:1.0
```

Here is `dmesg` output from another arch pc there all is ok:

```
[авг24 10:38] usb 2-1.5: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[  +0,744734] cdc_acm 2-1.5:1.1: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[  +0,000313] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[  +0,000002] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
[  +0,006095] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[  +0,000026] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[  +0,000020] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[  +0,027784] usbcore: registered new interface driver option
[  +0,000021] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
[  +2,089085] usb 2-1.5: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  +0,975236] usb 2-1.5: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[  +0,702057] usb-storage 2-1.5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  +0,004262] scsi host6: usb-storage 2-1.5:1.0
[  +0,000454] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  +0,003760] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  +1,021324] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     MEDIATEK  FLASH DISK           PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[  +0,000847] scsi 6:0:0:1: Direct-Access     MEDIATEK  FLASH DISK           PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[  +0,006886] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdc] 20480 512-byte logical blocks: (10.5 MB/10.0 MiB)
[  +0,001989] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  +0,001248] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[  +0,000007] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdc] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[  +0,000965] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[  +0,000009] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  +0,013823]  sdc:
[  +0,007568] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

I'm tried to connect it with 4 different cables, into 3 different usb 3.0 and 2 different usb 2.0, result stays same.
I'm also changed my LinkitOne with another one, but nothing has changed.

P.S.: I forgot to say that the problem appeared a few of days ago, before everything worked as it should.

Comment: What is the USB device? It is showing there it is only `10MiB` in size

Comment: @HostFission, this is my LinkitOne. There is actually 10MiB of storage